# Onchange event not working on dynamic table row

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I output the counter variable so that it displays the row count for each row.
This is on a dynamically created table row so the js I have posted is the dynamic code:

```
                counter = $('#myTable tr').length;
            var newRow = $("<tr>");
            var cols = "";
            cols += '<td row-id="' + counter + '"></td>';
            cols += '<td row-id="' + counter + '">Display row counter here</td>';
            cols += '<td row-id="' + counter + '"><div class="input-group"><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="material_id_' + counter + '" readonly="true" name="material_id_' + counter + '" style="width:150px" required><span class="btn btn-default btn-sm input-group-addon search_material_modal" id="" onclick="displaymaterialmodal(' + counter + ')" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" title="' + counter + ' "></span></span></div></td>';
            cols += '<td row-id="' + counter + '"><div class="input-group"><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="description_' + counter + '" name="description_' + counter + '" readonly="true" style="width:200px"></div></td>';
            cols += '<td row-id="' + counter + '"><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm myInputbox" id="quantity" name="quantity" style="width:70px"></td>';
            cols += '<td row-id="' + counter + '"><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm myInputbox" id="bar_code" name="bar_code" style="width:150px"></td>';
            cols += '<td row-id="' + counter + '"><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm myInputbox" id="invoice_number" name="invoice_number" style="width:150px"></td>';
            cols += '<td row-id="' + counter + '"><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm myInputbox" id="unit_price" name="unit_price" style="width:100px"></td>';
            cols += '<td row-id="' + counter + '"><select name="where_found" id="where_found" style="height:30px"><option value="" selected></option><option value="Retour client"><cfoutput>#textconstants.customer#</cfoutput></option><option value="Controle recption"><cfoutput>#textconstants.quality_control#</cfoutput></option></select></td>';
            cols += '<td row-id="' + counter + '"><select name="shipment" id="shipment" style="height:30px" class="myInputbox"><option value="" selected></option><option value="Pallette"><cfoutput>#textconstants.pallet#</cfoutput></option><option value="Container"><cfoutput>#textconstants.container#</cfoutput></option></select></td>';
            cols += '<td row-id="' + counter + '"><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm myInputbox" id="remarks" name="remarks_' + counter + '" ondblclick="openRemarksModal('+ counter +',$(this).val());"></td>';
            cols += '<td row-id="' + counter + '"><select name="rework" id="rework" style="height:30px" class="myInputbox"><option value="" selected></option><cfoutput><option value="#textconstants.no_rework#">#textconstants.no_rework#</option><option value="#textconstants.failed_rework#">#textconstants.failed_rework#</option><option value="#textconstants.rework_ok#">#textconstants.rework_ok#</option></cfoutput></select></td>';
            cols += '<td row-id="' + counter + '"><select name="status" id="status" style="height:30px" class="myInputbox"><cfoutput><option value="" selected></option><option value="#textconstants.credit_note#">#textconstants.credit_note#</option><option value="#textconstants.replacement#">#textconstants.replacement#</option><option value="#textconstants.no_action#">#textconstants.no_action#</option></cfoutput></select></td>';
            cols += '<td row-id="' + counter + '"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" onclick="addphotos(' + counter + ')"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera"></span></button></td>';

            newRow.append(cols);
            counter++;
            $("table.order-list").append(newRow);
            $('#url_total_rows').val(parseInt($('#url_total_rows').val(), 10) + 1);


        });

        $("#myTable tbody").on("change", ".myInputbox", function(){
            var row = $(this).closest("tr");
            var tb1 = row.find("input.quantity").val();
            console.log(tb1);
        });
```

Any ideas would be appreciated, having a mind block on getting this to output.

Comment: Holy macaroni! I did not take time to read your code but i'm pretty sure there is a better to do that...

Comment: "Jeepers creepers" indeed! That's a painful way to create rows and assign styles and handlers.

Comment: Do you actually have a bunch of global variables named `rework_` and `invoice_number_` and so on, each with a unique trailing number for each row? Did you mean for them to be ID selectors, like `$("#rework_???")`

Comment: yeah you are correct, the traliing ids are no longer required this was used before I switched to using ajax to update the rows when the values get changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well just looking at the code it would render something like this:

```
$(material_id_12)
```

Do you have a variable named `material_id_12` or are you actually trying to reference an element with that id.

AKA, it should probably look like

```
$("#material_id_12")
```

You have this issue in a couple of places with all of the selectors.

---

Since you are using jQuery, you probalby should rely on a single selector and fine the values based on that row. There is no need to add events directly to every element.

```
$("#tableId tbody").on("change", ".classForTextbox", function(){
    var row = $(this).closest("tr");
    var tb1 = row.find("input.foo").val();
    var tb2 = row.find("input.bar").val();
    processMyData(tb1, tb2);
});
```

Comment: Ok appreciate your help epascarello and I see the error of my ways. I have removed the event calls and added in the jquery js but getting undefined in the console. I will update the above code to reflect what I have changed.